# Bootstrap Modal standard open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, modal-dialog

I have a Modal. My problem is that the modal will only open when clicking this button.

```
<button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#InfoModalColor2">TEST</button>
```

Is it possible to open the modal without clicking the button. 
I need to open it when i go directly to the page, i already tried: test.php#InfoModalColor2 but this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straight from the documents:

```
$('#InfoModalColor2').modal('show');
```

Just place that in a ready handler